# Android Drag Item Change

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-gridview

I create GridView Drag'n'Drop, and want to create when drag start: 
-item change scale 
-layout sets dark mask

My code

```
@Override
public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    holder = (Holder) view.getTag();
    mItem = (Item) mAdapter.getItem(i);

    ClipData.Item item = new ClipData.Item("","");
    ClipData clipData  = new ClipData(i+"", new String[]{ClipDescription.MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN}, item);

    View v = holder.image; 
    v.animate().scaleX(1.3f);// here i want to create Drag item bigger
    // and how i can create a mask for layout?


    holder.image.startDrag(clipData, new View.DragShadowBuilder(v), null, 0);

    holder.image.setOnDragListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.package_btn).setOnDragListener(this);

    mDragIndex = i;
    return true;
}
```